# Gostaria de saber como aplicar uma borda no elemento por meio de javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    
    function domingo(){
        var domingo= document.getElementById("domingoid");
        alert(domingo)
        
    }
```

```html
        <div class="btn" id="domingoid" onclick="domingo();">
            <h2 class="paddi"> DOMINGO </h2>
            <h3>20 de Outubro</h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: Qual elemento? Em qual momento?

Comment: Sem saber sob qual circunstancia deve ser aplicada a borda, dar uma resposta é algo complexo. Pois dependendo do momento em que deva ser aplicada a borda, a resposta pode não ser o que espera. Ex: caso o objetivo seja aplicar a borda reagindo a passagem do mouse, então a melhor e mais simples opção não é o Javascript,a melhor opção nesse cenário é o CSS usando a pseudo-classe `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a opção classList do javascript, para adicionar ou remover classes, ou então utilizar a propriedade style.

```js
let domingo = document.querySelector("#domingoid");

domingo.style.border = '1px solid blue';
domingo.style.borderRadius = '25px';
```